# Understanding a Complex Find Command

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

I am working on cleaning up script code on a linux machine that a previous developer had created when I came across this command:

```
find / -xdev -type f | egrep -v "^/etc/shadow|^/etc/random-seed|^/root/logs/|^/root/.ash|^/root/configs" | xargs md5sum 2> /dev/null | tr -s "[:space:]" | md5sum | cut -d\  -f1
```

I'm trying to fully wrap my head around what exactly each part of the command does, but the grep part is throwing me off.

I know that the output is essentially a checksum value of the file system, but I need to know exactly how it goes about doing this.

Thanks.

Comment: Why prune when you can grep? 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In slow-mo:

```
egrep -v "^/etc/shadow|^/etc/random-seed|^/root/logs/|^/root/.ash|^/root/configs"
```

- `egrep` means we are using EREs (Extended regexps)
- -v inverts the selection (keep what doesn't match)
- The `|` are ORing the various expressions
- `^` is the "start of line" match

So it removes the lines that start with `/etc/shadow`, `/etc/random-seed` etc... which excludes the files from these directories.

So globally:

- find all the files only in the `/` filesystem (due to `-xdev`), so this excludes `/proc` for instance and possibly other filesystems (given the rest, I wouldn't be surprised to se `/var` be a separate FS), and filter out specific directories as shown above.
- compute a MD5 hash of all these files (`xargs md5sum`)
- massage that list of hashes a bit
- compute a MD5 hash of the list of MD5 hashes `md5sum | cut -d\  -f1`

In other words, it computes a combined hash of all the files on the disk, likely to check that nothing has changed since the last time it was computed (which is why I would be surprised that /`var` is taken in account, since its contents change over time: `/var/log`, `/var/mail`, `/var/lib`...)

Comment: Thank you very much. This explained it clearly.

Could you also explain the remainder of the command?

`| xargs md5sum 2> /dev/null | tr -s "[:space:]" | md5sum | cut -d\  -f1`

I understand some of the parts but not how it all flows together.

Comment: I checked the file systems on this system and I found that "/ ", "/dev", "/dev/shm", and "/tmp" are separate filesystems but that /var is not. I'll have to modify this code then to include some of the missing directories. This would explain why the checksums always seem to report differences.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by xenoid is valid so I will not repeat it. A few more clarifications since lukemk1 asked for them in his comment above about this part:
| xargs md5sum 2> /dev/null | tr -s "[:space:]" | md5sum | cut -d\ -f1

"| xargs md5sum" : allows you to apply the md5sum command with the argument being all the piped filenames (it might be a bit more complex here).

"2> /dev/null" : means throw away the stderr stream

"| tr -s "[:space:]" ": (per "man tr" [:space:] is all horizontal or vertical whitespace and -s flag (--squeeze-repeats) squeezes consecutive repeats of this type of spaces.

"| md5sum" : takes the md5sum of the stream of md5sums

"| cut -d\  -f1 " : Using space ("\ ") as the delimiter fields, print only the first field (in effect just the md5sum number)

This was not part of the question, but one issue I see with the overall command is that if there is space in filenames, it will not work as expected; to correct, you need to use find ... -print0 | ....| xargs -0 ....